# Handle session using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, session

I just started learning Node.js and want to handle a session using MySQL database. I want to do it without express or any kind of framework. I searched through google but couldn't manage to get an answer to my query. My present condition of this task is: I designed my .html files, created HTTP server using http module, managed to connect the database, and now desperately want to create a session (when a user logged in) and destroy it.